# Deploy google apps script webui app

Tags: google-apps-script

All,

I have managed to create a standalone script using the WebUI method which collects some data and then stores this into a sheet.  The script works great for me, however I can't get it to work either for other users or anonymous people.
I am looking for some help and guidance on how to deploy this within a site for anyone to use.
To deploy I have gone to Publish -> Deploy and set it to execute as myself and allow anonymous access.

The script (code) can be viewed at:
https ://script.google.com/d/1INGGAx4Ep4gDJA9pNGNHVfHMHfQdV4Nh-pcPNPkHaBtazooZpffkbxVc/edit

The sheet can be viewed at:
https ://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhBJhk8_tFyWdE93TFR2cWQ1WnFiTjZzdVJIdFVRQkE

The deployed app can be viewed at:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx0G73V0hD4s8oo7NFZ877UsTh9SCxhnLlzCqoSID2gmX-rSwk/exec

It is also embedded in a site at:
https ://sites.google.com/a/clairescourt.net/ccoe/home/dofe/test

(note the spaces in the above links will need to be removed to make them work)

One other oddity is that the list boxes are not populated for anyone other than myself.

Many thanks

Paul

Answer (score 1):

I made a copy of yout script, deployed it like shown below and get this url :
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby7Ckir9e9erQ_ZSBhSH3SOy05hDbLV1yZCiqf2pwh_0DmsXuQ/exec

[image]

As you can test , it seems to work... I just get an error message telling me I can't write to the spreadsheet but this is normal since I can only view its content. If I change the ID of the SS to another one where I can write then I have no issue at all.

Can you (double)check your settings and my copy as well ?

Comment: My settings were identical to yours above.  I then created a new version, published it and it appears to work. (it is also 5 hours since the first time I published it with anonymous access).  Many thanks for your assistance